# How to send UDP/art-net command to LANBOX LCX in the same network?

Tags: udp, lighting, dmx512

I have a LANBOX LCX device which is used for lighting up a few dimmable bulbs which are connected via DMX cables.
I have read the documentation and tried to find ways to send UDP, but as I am a newbie in lighting and DMX world, it is so hard to understand it.
Documentation: http://support.lanbox.com/Manuals/LanBox%20Reference%203.04.pdf
I have also tried some art-net programs to send data through that and also sending the mentioned bytes via UDP also. But none of them worked.
There are not much online resources also for this area.
If someone with knowledge about this particular area can help me, it would be really helpful.
If someone can help me with either sending art-net or UDP commands to the device to dim specific lights and light up specific lights, it will be really helpful.

Tried with the following documentations and GitHub repos:

```
https://www.artisticlicence.com/WebSiteMaster/User%20Guides/art-net.pdf
http://support.lanbox.com/Manuals/LanBox%20Reference%203.04.pdf
https://github.com/MikeCodesDotNet/ArtNet.Net
https://pypi.org/project/pyartnet/
```

I wanted to change the values in the DMX monitor, but it doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

I share your pain, however I have spend a lot of time building library's for various applications to interface with Lanbox (node.js, Bright Script etc) and so I know everything there is to know about Lanbox (including the bugs)

you have found the correct ref docs

you need to connect via TCP
after you connect it will ask for a password , send this , it is default 777
then to edit channels direct you need to look at the command
#C9 ChannelSetData

make sure you check out the command
#65 Common16BitMode

as a lot of the docs ref 16 bit mode but when you connect it will be in 8bit mode so if you need int above 255 you have to set it into 16bit

let me know if you need more help, when i do lanbox training it takes a few hours to full explain how they work so its understandable if you are totally confused

Comment: We changed the whole device setup to a new device. This was too hard to handle.